# Batch script Is there a way to loop through a log of directories and look for a folder with a specific name in each directory

Tags: batch-file

Sorry if the question is confusing. Basically, I have a log.txt with a list of directories. Is there a way to loop through the list, and see if any of the directories contain a folder with a specific name.
So if the log has :

C:\test1

C:\test2

and we are looking for a folder called "test3" inside any of the directories in the log, then output that it was found.

edit:
I am new to batch and kinda mashed other code i found on here to make this, apologies if its a mess.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%Z in (%dir1%\log.txt) do (

    cd %%Z

    for /d /r "%%Z" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="test3" set "foldername=%%a"

    echo "%foldername%"
)
```

where dir1 is the directory I'm using elsewhere in the code, and test3 is the string I'm looking for in the subfolder name.

I think I need to use SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion? but I don't really understand it.

Comment: Show us the batch file code you've tried so far and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: sorry, I didnt really know where to start so i didnt have much code, I updated the post thank you

Comment: Your question states, "test3 is the string I'm looking for **in** the subfolder name.", but your code suggests, "test3 is the string I'm looking for **as** the subfolder name.". Which is true?

Comment: I am looking to see if a folder contained in each directory of the log file has the correctly named subfolder in it. So it should look inside C:\test1 for a folder with test3 in the name, then look in C:\test2 for a folder with test3 in the name. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You've continued to make your requirement unclear, is it supposed to be "with test3 in the name"? or "with the name test3"? For instance, is `TheFastest3Miles` supposed to match? or only `test3`?

Comment: with test3 in the name. the naming convention for all of the folders will be similar, such as test3_1, test3_2 , test3_3.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I see that i forgot the wildcard when searching for test3

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will return all lines within your text file that contain a folder name you specify:

```
type log.txt | findstr foldername
```

I tested this by creating a text file that contained the following:

> > test1 line 1 
> >     test2 line 2 
> >     test3 line 3 
> >     test2 line 4

And then I ran:

```
type mytextfile.txt | findstr test2
```

And it returned:

> > test2 line 2
> >     test2 line 4

Is this basically what you were looking for?

Comment: close. the text file should be directories, and then it should look in each directory to see if there is a folder called test3. so if the log file contains c:\test1 then c:\test2 then it should look in both for a folder called test3. apologies if my wording is confusing